# I need to rewrite part of original file

Tags: batch-file

I have a .csv file. In every 3rd and 4th column (except the 1st line), there is a date in the DDMMYY format. I need to rewrite it into DD.MM.20YY. So far I got this:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=; skip=1 tokens=3,4" %%a  in ("original.csv") DO (
echo %%a %%b
set datum=%%a
echo !datum:~0,2!
echo !datum:~2,2!
echo !datum:~4,2!
set %%a=%datum:~0,2%.%datum:~2,2%.20%datum:~4,2%
echo %%a
)
```

I have a feeling that using `set %%a` isn't working. Thank you in advance!

Comment: In batch, the `%%a` refers to the variable value, not the content of the file, so your suspicion is correct, you will need to regenerate the file contents

Comment: How do you expect the batch file to know how to turn `YY` into `YYYY`?

Comment: @Monacraft I see what you mean. I'll try.

Comment: @compo The line starting with set %%a.. I manually write 20 and then i add the YY. So yeah, it won't work in the year 2100 :-)

Comment: That's fine, I just wanted to verify the parameters of your question, so just change the last two lines before the closing parenthesis to, `set datum=!datum:~0,2!.!datum:~2,2!.20!datum:~4,2!` and `echo !datum!`. Just echo them in an appropriate way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q48492955.csv"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a  in ("%filename1%") DO >"%outfile%" ECHO %%a&GOTO :hdr
:hdr
(
for /f "usebackq  skip=1 tokens=1-4* delims=;" %%a  in ("%filename1%") DO (
 REM dates are in col3,4 = %%c,%%d
 set "datum1=%%c"
 set "datum2=%%d"
 ECHO %%a;%%b;!datum1:~0,2!.!datum1:~2,2!.20!datum1:~4,2!;!datum2:~0,2!.!datum2:~2,2!.20!datum2:~4,2!;%%e
)
)>>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q48492955.csv` containing some dummy data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

The first few lines simply establish the file locations that suit my system.

The first `for` reads the header line and outputs it to the output file, then immediately jumps to `:hdr` so only the one line is processed.

Notice that the remainder of the code is contained within `(...)>>"%outfile%"`. This gathers any output `echo`ed within the block and redirects it to *append* (`>>`) to the output file.

The second `for` loop assigns the first 4 tokens and *remainder of line* to `%%a`..`%%e`. There is no facility to assign *the part before the first token* in batch, so each of the tokens must be assigned individually.

So - `set` the two date variables required to the values of the two tokens required, then `echo` the result, regurgitating the first 2 tokens and the last and replacing the third and fourth with the modified string. Note that since `delayedexpansion` is in effect, `!varexpression!` acts on the *current* value of `var`, not the *initial* value given by `%varexpression%` - many, many SO articles about this (usethe search faility for `delayed expansion`)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your task correctly, something like this may be similar to your requirements.

```bat
@Echo Off
Set /P "header="<"original.csv">"modified.csv"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
    For /F "UseBackQ Skip=1 Tokens=1-4* Delims=;" %%A  In ("original.csv") Do (
        Set "cols=%%C;%%D"
        Set "cols=!cols:~,2!.!cols:~2,2!.20!cols:~4,5!.!cols:~9,2.20!cols:~11,2"
        Echo %%A;%%B;!cols!;%%E
    )
)>>"modified.csv"
Rem Del "original.csv"
Rem Ren "modified.csv" "original.csv"
```

*Un`Rem`ark the last lines if `modified.csv` contains the required data and you wish to rename it overwriting the original.*